# How can I fix error with version of PHP on Mercado Libre API

Tags: php, api, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

I'm trying to integrate Mercado Pago to my project. In the back end the documentation says that we should put.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");
```

But MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN"); gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerFile() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tiendaFarias/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php:75 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tiendaFarias/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/MetaDataReader.php(27): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerFile('/Applications/X...') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tiendaFarias/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Manager.php(42): MercadoPago\MetaDataReader->__construct() #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tiendaFarias/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/SDK.php(34): MercadoPago\Manager->__construct(Object(MercadoPago\RestClient), Object(MercadoPago\Config)) #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tiendaFarias/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/SDK.php(43): MercadoPago\SDK::initialize() #4 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tiendaFarias/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 75
```

It's important to say that I'm using php V 7.0.33

I hope someone can tell if I'm missing something.

Comment: Update PHP, I not sure how you installed the package as it should have let you know you need >7.1.0 see composer.json: https://github.com/mercadopago/dx-php/blob/master/composer.json#L26

Comment: if you set the version in your composer to [1.9.0](https://github.com/mercadopago/dx-php/blob/1.9.0/composer.json), that should fix it

Comment: The documentation say that we should use php 5.6 or higher. I installed the package with this command php composer.phar require "mercadopago/dx-php" .

Comment: it mentions in the readme how to install for < 7.1 https://github.com/mercadopago/dx-php#-installation `composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:1.8.1"` or better `composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:1.9.0"`

Comment: wow, the documentation  in https://www.mercadopago.cl/developers/es/guides/sdks/official/php/ don't says that haha. I will delete the files that create the command php composer.phar require "mercadopago/dx-php" and I will try with composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:1.8.1"

Comment: noone likes updating docs ;p [suggest an edit](https://github.com/mercadopago/devsite-docs/edit/development/guides/sdks/official/php.es.md).

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I works with out problem! =) I was following the official  documentation thinking it was the right thing and nothing. You really help me a lot. I will continue implementing hopping not to have any problems. If I have a question can I ask you?